# How do you prevent glitches using vector3 components even though I already have collider and rigidbody

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble in controlling my character when I command it on speech and I used the vector3 components that will trigger the command then when my character reaches my collider it glitches through does anyone experience this scenario?

Here's the code I used

```
Cube.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Separate speech-recognition from your problem, it's probably not relevant. And add a snippet of your movement code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from trying to directly set the position of a transform with a position. Moving the transform causes the character to move through other collider without the physics engine getting involved (there's no collisions being checked when to move with Translate).

Instead use a [Character Controller](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html) and one of the move functions such as [**SimpleMove**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html).

Or use a [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) and [**AddForce**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

These are all basics Unity concepts covered [here](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules)